# Related entities not loaded - EAGER ignored?

Tags: jpa, ejb, eclipselink, glassfish-3

Got GlassFish v3. I have an one-to-many entity. The problem is, that `EclipseLink` seems to ignore the fetch EAGER mode.

Here is my entities.

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Hobby> hobbies;

    // getter and setter
}
```

A `1:n` relationship

```
@Entity
public class Hobby
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;    

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Person person;

    // getter and setter
}
```

And the bean

```
@javax.ejb.Remote
public interface Testing
{
    public void addTestData();
    public List<Person> getTestData();
}

@javax.ejb.Stateless
public class TestingBean implements Testing
{
    @javax.persistence.PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void addTestData()
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setName("JOE");
        entityManager.persist(p);

        Hobby h1 = new Hobby();
        h1.setName("h1");
        h1.setPerson(p);

        entityManager.persist(h1);              
    }

    public List<Person> getTestData()
    {
        TypedQuery<Person> gridQuery = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Person e", Person.class);
        return gridQuery.getResultList();
    }
}
```

EDIT Client:

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();      
Testing test = (Testing)context.lookup("java:global/dst2_1/TestingBean");

test.addTestData();

for(Person p: test.getTestData()) {
    System.out.println(p.getName());
    for(Hobby b : p.getHobbys()) {                  
        System.out.println(b.getName());
    }
}

context.close();
```

Using `MySQL` - Storing the data works. But if I fetch the data only the person is returned - not hobbies. Coudld you tell me what is wrong in my code?

EDIT sorry have tried so many things ... The code shown as above produces:

> Exception Description: An attempt was made to traverse a
>   relationship using indirection    that had a null Session.  This often
>   occurs when a n entity with an uninstantiated LAZY relationship is
>   serialized and that lazy relationship is traversed after
>   serialization.  To avoid this issue, ins tantiate the LAZY
>   relationship prior to serialization.

But the Person is returned correctly. Why does it specify LAZY while I am using EAGER?

Comment: Can you show the code you use for getting hobbies?

Comment: You mean the client? I have updated my post :)

Comment: Are you populating the p.hobbies collection?  If not, this is why it would be empty when you read back the person entity.  You must maintain both sides of a bidirectional relationship so that the cache is consistent with what is in the database.  As for the Lazy, can you give more information on which relationship it is occuring on, and the stack trace?

Comment: @Chris: i also tried to flush / clear the EntityManager after insetion ...
Last call is org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.instantiatingValueholderWithNullSession(ValidationException.java:979)

Comment: EclipseLInk uses a second level cache which flush/clear might not touch - you must use the refresh query hint or call em.refresh(p); though it is better if you just update both sides of a relationship when it changes.  As for the exception, can you post the full stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code looks correct.  I can't see any way that the EAGER could be ignored.

Are you sure you get the error with this attribute, not another one?

Also ensure you recompile and deployed your code correctly.  You most like have an old version deployed.

Comment: Yes - i spend 10 hours yesterday on that problem ;) Restarted the domain several times - deployment works [throw some custom Exceptions to check if it deployed correctly]. A colleague of mine had the same issues on his machine. I have to use "Glassfish v3 final" - a quite old version. Tried in Hibernate - worked. Maybe there is a bug?
Its also quite funny that if the annotation is on the variable it has a different behaviour than on the getter: on the getter eclipselink creates a linked table?!

Comment: If it is on the getter and you get a linked table, then it is because the annotation is ignored.  You cannot mix annotation types on an entity - they must all be on the properties, or all on the fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Setting both directions was the problem - it works now. Annotations are now on all variables

Answer (score 1):

Make the eager object `Serializable`